# Meta-analysis of "adjusted r-squared" from multiple prediction models

Tags: meta-analysis, r-squared

Using data from multiple cohorts, I am trying to check the performance of a prediction model I developed. The plan is to get the Adjusted r-squared from 2 models, one model has the score and the other doesn't have it. After I collected the Adjusted r-squared values, I am not sure how to meta-analyze the r-squared values of models I ran on data from the 4 different studies. Should that be different from any other meta-analysis of standard effect sizes as odds ratios or estimates?

Any help on sources of similar analysis or advice would be much appreciated.

Cheers!
Mohammed